# Opencv CV ColorHSV error

Tags: c, xcode, opencv, artoolkit

can anyone tell me why i am getting this error?
[image]

because of that I'm getting this error too
[image]

Trying to integrate opencv with artoolkit

Comment: What's wrong with pasting code? Can't help you with this short snippet. At least share the entire function.

Comment: Add the C tag to this question since you are sharing C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruben, we've talked about this on Tweeter. This is a **compiling error** that is telling you that **it doesn't know what `colorHSV` is**.

Looking at your code and the error message, I can tell that `colorHSV` is a **class** that should be defined in your code or in one of the 3rd party libraries you are using.

I've done some research and I found a [code very similar to yours](http://se.cs.ait.ac.th/cvwiki/opencv%3atutorial%3aintegrate_opencv_and_artoolkit). Apparently, `colorHSV` is a custom data type that the developer uses, but the page doesn't provide the entire source code of the application, just a few snippets here and there to give directions. In other words, there's a lot of code missing in that post.

**However**, they do mention using a technology for Augmented Reality named **Occlusion**. A little bit more of research showed me [ait-occlusion](http://code.google.com/p/ait-occlusion/), which [implements a `colorHSV`](http://ait-occlusion.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Occlusion/Occlusion/ColorHSV.h). **This seems to be the same type you are using in your code.**

If you still haven't figured it out, you need to:

- **download/compile/install Occlusion** on your system,
- add the proper `#include` for `ColorHSV.h`,
- and finally adjust your project properties to link your application with this library.

If you have any doubts on any of these procedures, [Google it](https://www.google.com).

Comment: uhm right @Karl thanks i thought colorHSV was a opencv class, but i have to implemented, know its make sense, yes i use that tutorial to integrate opencv and artoolkit, tell me see it better thanks again

Comment: hi Karl if i copy the coloHSV.h and paste it I'm my opencv framework folder will it work?

Comment: How about you try that and come back to us later with the result?

Comment: uhm i still got the problem maybe the problem its here
        class ColorHSV2
Class it a c++ code? still have the erro but in colorHSV.h that strange because here is there there declared colorHSV :(

Comment: Is it the same error msg? You are probably missing something obvious. I wont be able to help you further without looking at the code.

Comment: i guess i must had a lot of header but the code its for C++ and I'm coding in C :(( try to use the code without the colorHSV but i get a flipped image after i put the marker to be detected

Comment: uhm the colorhsv need a lot of other headers but the code its for C++ and i am coding in C

Comment: Sounds like you have to make a decision: either drop the code you found and start writing your own, or start using a C++ compiler :)